# Git pull - fatal: read error: Invalid argument

Tags: git, msysgit

I'm trying to pull using msysgit 1.8.1 (tried with 1.7.10 and .11, too, with the same result) and always get an error which I don't know how to debug/resolve:

```
E:\java\myproject>git pull
Enter passphrase for key '/E/my-private-key':
remote: Counting objects: 200, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (97/97), done.
rRemote: Total 115 (delta 66), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (115/115), 12.25 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (66/66), completed with 34 local objects.
From ssh://myserver:12345/myproject
   50e90d7..d24b154  release-4.5 -> origin/release-4.5
   58625d6..960fcc6  develop    -> origin/develop
 * [new branch]      release/4.6 -> origin/release/4.6
 * [new tag]         4.6-rc-1   -> 4.6-rc-1
Fetching submodule src/jgit/main
fatal: read error: Invalid argument

E:\java\myproject>
```

Between

```
Fetching submodule src/jgit/main
```

and

```
fatal: read error: Invalid argument
```

it takes approximately 5min (timeout?).

What also is strange, that one line starts with `rRemote` - a bug in msysgit?

Comment: Do you get the `not in list of known hosts` every time too? Shouldn't it be added to `.ssh/hosts`? Is your `.ssh` folder writeable?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Git for Windows (what OP wrongly called "msysgit") does not make use of Cygwin and neither does it link with `cygwin.dll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloning/pulling from `ssh://myserver:12345/myproject` works well.

But pulling from the url recorded in the `.gitmodules` file of that repo, for the submodule "`src/jgit/main`" doesn't.

Check said url, and see if another protocol (https instead of ssh for instance) might work (again, for the url of the submodule, as specified in the `.gitmodules` file of the repo you just pulled).

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason: the submodule `src/jgit/main` had two externals. `origin` pointed to the official jgit repository and another to our clone of the jgit repository. After removing `origin` and renaming the other to `origin`, it works. Looks like I had problems pulling from the official jgit repository.

Comment: +1. This confirms my own answer regarding an issue with the submodule url.