# git error: read error while indexing: Invalid argument

Tags: git, git-index

I'm initializing a repo in a Google Drive folder which contains a gsheet file. When I index the folder this error happens:

```
git add .
error: read error while indexing file.gsheet: Invalid argument
error: file.gsheet: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file 'file.gsheet'
```

Do you know why is that? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17233108/3416774) asking for the same error but I don't know how to apply it to my case.

Comment: Might be a permissions error. Is the file is open in another application?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander no, I don't think so

Comment: This is generally some sort of OS-level error. (You could get it from a bug in Git, but this kind of bug in Git would be caught during testing.) You could get this error when trying to use a cloud-synced folder, for instance; the solution in that case is to avoid using Git with cloud-synced folders.